# String array in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a string array(strLarge) containing 5 values say 1,2,3,4,5.
I have another string(strSmall) containing a value say 3.

Now I need to remove this strSmall from strLarge and finally get the result as 1,2,4,5.

Comment: What's your framework version?

Answer (score 3):

```
strLarge.Except(strSmall);
```

in LINQ

> Produces the set difference of two
>   sequences.

See

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx)

Comment: Add ".ToArray()" to the end if the result should an array of String and not an IEnumerable<String>.

Answer (score 1):

```
   string[] strLarge = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
   string[] strSmall = { "3" };

   strLarge = strLarge.Where(x => !strSmall.Contains(x)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

use Except() for strLarge